# Trying to understand Battery Chargers

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I just started studying about batteries and battery chargers. I have this simple query so please help me out.

I am trying to charge my 3000mah li-ion battery. The battery voltage is around 3.6v and the charger regulates the 5v from the source to 4.2v. I connect the battery to the charger. Now what is the voltage at the output should I expect?
Shouldn't the output voltage be at 4.2v so that the battery gradually charges to 4.2v ? I ask this because I am using Bq2057 IC and once I connect to the battery to the charger the output voltage is dropping to 3.63v.

My assumptions were,
1. I considered the charger as voltage source
2. Battery also as a voltage source

I experimented this buy connecting two DC voltage sources(5 and 3.3v) in parallel and measured the voltage at the node and it was 5v. So I was expecting the charger output to be 4.2v even when I connected my battery to it.

Thanks

Comment: "connecting two DC voltage sources(5 and 3.3v) in parallel" - please don't do this. You might get lucky, but often, one, or both or the sources will die. Imagine two 'ideal' sources; for the 1.7V difference to be 'absorbed' in the wiring, a significant amount if current is required assuming your wiring resistance is low.

Comment: This simple logic (constant voltage charging) kind of (and only "kind of") works for chemistries with huge overload tolerances, like lead-acid. Even nickel based cells are much more complicated in charging (look for "negative delta-V"), and lithium ones demand the most sophisticated logic. Otherwise they catch fire.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My assumptions were,
>
> 1. I considered the charger as voltage source
> 2. Battery also as a voltage source

Your 2<sup>nd</sup> assumption is more a less correct.

Your 1<sup>st</sup> assumptions is not entirely correct.  Li-ion<sup>1</sup> chargers start with constant curent charging (charger is a current source), then switch to constant voltage charging.

[image]
([Source of the plot.](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries)  By the way, that entire site is an excellent resource on battery topics.)

Finally, I'd like to warn that you should be very careful with Li-ion batteries, because they catch fire when improperly charged (more on that [here](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/safety_concerns_with_li_ion)).  Consider a safer battery chemistry, for your introductory experiments.  Lead-acid or NiMH batteries are more abuse-tolerant and less risky.

<sup>1</sup> Charging profile varies from one battery chemistry to another.
<sup>2</sup> Related thread: [Difference between controlled current and constant voltage charging](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/210628/7036)

Comment: ...because they can catch fire **or explode** when improperly charged.  This really can't be stressed enough.  Experimenting with Li-ion charging needs safety precautions.  A fireproof blast shield, at least even a modest one, around the apparatus should be a minimum.